# Accessing ArcGIS Pro conda env in R

Tags: python, r, arcgis-pro, installation, anaconda

Environment: Windows 7, ArcGIS Pro 2.1, R 3.5.1 with reticulate v1.10.

ArcGIS Pro comes with a pre-configured python 3 conda environment that I'm trying to access in R. Related questions here and at stackoverflow all seem to focus on a similar situation with ArcMap 10.x, but that uses python 2.7 and doesn't use conda, so they haven't been much help.

If I'm reading the `reticulate` documentation correctly, the following should work:

```
library(reticulate)

arcpy3_dir <- 'C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python'

use_condaenv(condaenv = file.path(arcpy3_dir, 'envs', 'arcgispro-py3'),
             conda    = file.path(arcpy3_dir, 'Scripts' ,'conda.exe'), 
             required = TRUE)
```

However, I'm getting an 'unable to locate conda environment' error.

There are some .bat files in the same directory as conda.exe that seem to do a lot of temporary messing about with system paths ([more commentary here](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-8359) for an older version of ArcGIS Pro), but I don't know enough about shell scripts to clearly understand what they're doing. I think I need to set some environment variables with `Sys.setenv()`, but I'm not sure which. I tried

```
Sys.setenv('CONDA_NEW_ENV' = 'C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3',
           'CONDA_EXE'     = file.path(arcpy3_dir, 'Scripts' ,'conda.exe'),
           'CONDA_SCRIPTS' = file.path(arcpy3_dir, 'Scripts'))
```

but that doesn't appear to be sufficient.

Has anyone managed to successfully access the ArcGIS Pro conda environment in R, using `reticulate`?

Comment: You have the correct environment but you have to call Conda activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally cracked this (I am now using Win10, ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4 and R 3.6.1, but that shouldn't matter):

```
library(reticulate)
arcpy3_dir <- 'C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python'
system2(file.path(arcpy3_dir, 'Scripts', 'proenv.bat'))
```

Then you can

```
import('arcpy')
```

and proceed, or use `{python}` chunks in an R markdown document e.g.

````
```{python}
import arcpy
/* etc */
```
````